# TYPO3 - how to properly define constant, store it into variable and use inside of fluid template

Tags: typo3, fluid

In the Fluid template of plugin I am working on, some things are hardcoded. For instance:

```
<f:else>
                <li>
                    <v:page.link pageUid="114" />
                </li>
            </f:else>
```

Since **pageUid** values are not same on test and production server I would like to make this more dynamic.

I would like to store this somehow in variable and then use the variable in the fluid template.

I just dont know hot to make this and where in TYPO3.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please improve formatting of code snippet

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because it is an setting do it like this:

Constants:

```
plugin.myext.settings.detailPid = 123
```

Setup:

```
plugin.myext.settings.detailPid = {$plugin.myext.settings.detailPid}
```

Variables are for variable content. If you have the same PID using variables with TEXT or similiar is overdressed and settings are the correct way.

**Also variables are only accessable for FLUIDTEMPLATE content element, not for plugins!**

Also in your extbase controller you can access these settings by simple access `$this->settings['detailPid']`without to render the cObjects first.

In your fluid you can access settings by `{settings.detailPid}`.

Comment: Should that be FLUIDTEMPLATE instead of FLUID_TEMPLATE?

Comment: I don't understand this sentence "If you have the same PID using variables with TEXT or similiar is overdressed and settings are the correct way."

Comment: @SybillePeters this sentence was related to another answer which used variables and `pageUid = TEXT`.

Comment: I find this answer a bit difficult to understand. You use the term "Variables". Do you mean variables in FLUIDTEMPLATE? Perhaps it might be helpful to update the answer so it can be clearer. I think it's just those 2 sentences, the rest ist clear.

Answer (score 5):

In typoscript template for your content object FLUIDTEMPLATE:

Typoscript setup/configuration:

```
10 = FLUIDTEMPLATE
10 {
    variables {
        pageUid = TEXT
        pageUid.value = 114
    }
}
```

or using constants

Typoscript constants:

```
pageUid = 114
```

Typoscript setup/configuration:

```
10 = FLUIDTEMPLATE
10 {
    variables {
        pageUid = TEXT
        pageUid.value = {$pageUid}
    }
}
```

Then you can fetch `pageUid` in your Fluid HTML

```
<f:else>
    <li>
        <v:page.link pageUid="{pageUid}" />
    </li>
</f:else>
```

To use variables in a Fluid *partial*, make sure to pass these along, e.g. by providing `_all`:

```
<f:render partial="fluid_part_header" arguments="{_all}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use `EXT:vhs` anyways, you can do the following to:

TS-Constants:

`pageUid=114`

TS-Setup:

`settings.pageUid = {$pageUid}`

Template (Fluid)

```
<f:else>
    <li>
        <v:page.link pageUid="{v:variable.typoscript(path: 'settings.pageUid')}" />
    </li>
</f:else>
```

This will make it available for all FLUID Templates.

Comment: You don't need vhs to access Typoscript. {f:cObject(typoscriptObjectPath: 'settings.pageUid')}} should do the job, too.
<v:page.link pageUid="{pageUid}" /> can also be replaced by <f:link.page pageUid="{f:cObject(typoscriptObjectPath: 'settings.pageUid')}}" />

Answer (score 0):

Please consider using jokumer's solution.
randomresult's solution would work, but I wouldn't suggest it. You don't need vhs to pass variables.
Not talking about  Paul Beck`s solution, because it wouldn't work at all. Not anymore at least. (See TYPO3\CMS\Fluid\ViewHelpers\CObjectViewHelper, https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/ExtbaseGuide/Fluid/ViewHelper/CObject.html). It accepts only content objects.

Set your Pid in constants like `PID_SOME_PAGE = 123` and set a variable in your plugins settings. Like this:

```
plugin.tx_yourplugin {
  ...
  settings{
    somePage = {$PID_SOME_PAGE}
  }
  ...
}
```

You can bypass that constants version if you want and set your page id in settings directly. It's just a cleaner way in my opinion, especially for larger websites.
Then you can use that variable in your template, like this `<f:link.page pageUid="{settings.somePage}">Go to Page</f:link.page>`. More options for f:link.page here: https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/ExtbaseGuide/Fluid/ViewHelper/Link/Page.html