# Pass settings to FLUIDTEMPLATE

Tags: typo3

The questions and answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41955828/typo3-how-to-properly-define-constant-store-it-into-variable-and-use-inside-o) already explain how to use constants in plugins and / or constants in templates based on FLUIDTEMPLATE.

What I would like to do is something like in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41956201/2444812

but not have to assign each setting individually but put them in a container and assign that as variable. For plugins there is a mechanism to be able to access the settings easily, via `{settings}` e.g. instead of doing:

```
10 = FLUIDTEMPLATE
10 {

    variables {
        setting1 = TEXT
        setting2.value = {$constant1}
        setting2 = TEXT
        setting2.value = {$constant2}
    }
```

I would like to do something (similar to):

```
lib.tx_myext.settings {
    setting1 = {$plugin.tx_myext.settings.setting1}  
    setting2 = {$plugin.tx_myext.settings.setting1}  
}

10 = FLUIDTEMPLATE
    10 {

        variables {
            settings < lib.tx_myext.settings
        }
```

And then use this in Fluid like `{settings.setting1}`.

Comment: Maybe a DataProcessor like this one can help you: https://github.com/portrino/px_semantic/blob/master/Classes/Processor/TypoScriptProcessor.php

Comment: little bit late to the party, but in similar need I ended up with custom ViewHelper(s) to fetch settings and/or conditionally display template/layout/partial's elements basing on plugins settings.  Works quite cool, if somebody needs someyhing like this I can write a sample. (contact via my profile's e-mail)

Answer (score 1):

In this case `lib.tx_myext.settings` resolves to a simple map of plain values so you can just copy that into `settings` instead:

```
10 = FLUIDTEMPLATE
10 {
  settings < lib.tx_myext.settings
}
```

If you have existing `settings` you can add them afterwards:

```
10 = FLUIDTEMPLATE
10 {
  settings < lib.tx_myext.settings
  settings {
    custom1 = ...
  }
}
```

Comment: For some reason this did not work for me. But I will check again and try to find out what the problem is exactly. (sometimes it's just a simple typo ....)